# Dashboard/Report to display the data counts

Tags: administration, reporting

I am trying to find out a way to report on all the data counts in the Organization. So one report to get all the objects and their data counts in the system. I don't see any standard way to built that report and i thought of custom approach too which will hit the governor limits since we have 350 custom objects in our system.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this or do you suggest any appexchange tool that can perform this?

Below is the kind of report i am looking for:

```
Object Name   Data Count
Account         1000
Contact         2000
```

Answer (score 3):

If your objective is merely to monitor data volumes, you can see this in Setup > Company Profile > Company Information.

There you see a link for Used Data Space which you can click on and it takes you to a page which gives you a list of objects that are using the most storage along with their record counts.

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_profile.htm

http://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_monitorresources.htm

Comment: The only caveat is that "Manage Users" is needed if non-SysAdmin wants to look at it.

Comment: Interesting never knew the data count was categorized so granular by Sobjects!!!

Comment: @eyescream One simple trick would be to login as the sysadmin and see :P ( not the best approach )!! You exactly asked the point I wanted to ask. How would the admin send this info to a user who does not have " manage user" priviledge

Comment: Looking at the help doc : Click Your Name | Setup | Manage Users | Users.
Click the name of any user.
Click View next to the Used Data Space or Used File Space fields to view that user’s storage usage by record type. Every user can see the actual data usage related to him/her,but not sure how the total view could be reported for a non admin user

Comment: @eyescream View Setup and Configuration rather than Manage Users as per the link.

Comment: @techtrekker  To view the companyprofile the user needs " view setup and configuration" and I also see from the doc when you click on the help for this page link on the monitor resource you pointed says <br/> Resources Available in: All Editions User Permissions Needed To view storage usage: “Manage Users”. In short the user needs both " view setup" as well as " manage user" privileged to see the data count.

Comment: I'm wondering if you'd need both as you wouldn't be able to get to the Company Information Page without the View Setup and Configuration ?